# Adjusting the bin size of a barplot in Rstudio

Tags: r

I'm looking to make a simple bar chart of a random number list (1-10) with the following code

```
Random.Integer.Data = table(Problem.2.Data$Random.Integer)
barplot(Random.Integer.Data, col = "Orange", main = "Random Integer", xlab = "Number Choice", ylab = "Frequency")
```

When I use this code, it creates a bar plot with the number 1 6 9 on the x axis. It also only creates 8 bars for me which means it is binning the random integers strangely. I would like their to be a single bar for each number between 1 and 10, and I'd like the x axis to show this as well.

Can someone help me with the code I need in order to do this?

Comment: Please make your question reproducible: add `Problem.2.Data$Random.Integer` to the question. Use `dput(Problem.2.Data$Random.Integer)` or dput(head(Problem.2.Data$Random.Integer, n)) where n is some integer large enough to make the question meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. There's something wrong with the assumptions you have about your data.

Let's try to recreate a data frame with the same name and column heading, and we'll fill it with 100 random integers between 1 and 10:

```r
set.seed(69)

Problem.2.Data <- data.frame(Random.Integer = sample(10, 100, TRUE))
head(Problem.2.Data)
#>   Random.Integer
#> 1              1
#> 2              2
#> 3              8
#> 4              7
#> 5              7
#> 6              6
```

Now we'll use your exact code, and see that it works as expected:

```r
Random.Integer.Data = table(Problem.2.Data$Random.Integer)
barplot(Random.Integer.Data, 
        col = "Orange", 
        main = "Random Integer", 
        xlab = "Number Choice", 
        ylab = "Frequency")
```

[image]

However, let's try it again with a smaller sample size, just 20 rows:

```r
Problem.2.Data <- data.frame(Random.Integer = sample(10, 20, TRUE))
head(Problem.2.Data)
#>   Random.Integer
#> 1              8
#> 2              5
#> 3              6
#> 4              8
#> 5              4
#> 6              6

Random.Integer.Data = table(Problem.2.Data$Random.Integer)
barplot(Random.Integer.Data, 
        col = "Orange", 
        main = "Random Integer", 
        xlab = "Number Choice", 
        ylab = "Frequency")
```

[image]

Now we can see there are only 7 bins. Why? Because if we look at our table, there are only 7 unique integers in our data:

```r
Random.Integer.Data
#> 
#>  3  4  5  6  8  9 10 
#>  1  1  5  5  5  1  2
```

We can fix this by making our column a factor with 10 levels:

```r
Random.Integer.Data = table(factor(Problem.2.Data$Random.Integer, 1:10))
barplot(Random.Integer.Data, 
        col = "Orange", 
        main = "Random Integer", 
        xlab = "Number Choice", 
        ylab = "Frequency")
```

[image]

Also note that if I shrink the window down some of the x axis labels disappear to prevent overlaps:

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your help! This gave me the 10 bars like I wanted however it is still only labeling the x axis as 1 5  9. Is there a setting to make a plots show each individual number choice?

Comment: @Jordan have you tried just dragging the plot window to make it bigger? All the labels should show by default, but if the plot area is too small relative to the text size, some of the numbers will be suppressed  to prevent overlaps.

Comment: Yep that fixed it. Sorry brand new to the software so still getting acquainted with the little things!

Answer (score 0):

If you want 10 bins and you feel like using something else then ggplot2 can give you the same result. As mentioned above, you also need that column with 10 factors.

```
#install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
df<-data.frame(x=seq(1:10),
               y=sample(10,10,TRUE)) #your data
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(x),y=y))+
  geom_col(fill="Orange")+
  labs(title =  "Random Integer", x = "Number Choice", y = "Frequency")
```